# How do I advance to the next occurrence of a variable in R Studio IDE

Tags: r, rstudio

When I highlight any string of text in the R Studio console a rectangle is drawn around all other occurrences of this same string of text. How do I advance to the next occurrence of this arbitrary string of text? I'd like the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> is the closest shortcut I know. This takes the selected string of text, drops it into the Find dialog and jumps to the next occurrence (keep pressing CTRL-F3 to cycle through)

Comment: this also works on major text editors like `Atom` or `Sublime Text`

Answer (score 6):

**If you would like to move to the next occurrence of a word/variable and select it while also keeping the original selected**, this command exists but does not have a default shortcut assigned to it.
The command is called 'Find and add next' (or 'Quick Add Next' in older versions). You can assign a shortcut to it by going into Preferences -> Code -> Modify_Keyboard_Shortcuts. I use Alt+Cmd+Right (on a Mac) as that is an unassigned key binding.
You can see bellow I have used the command twice to select three of the four instances.

[image]

Comment: In the current version of Rstudio this now seems to be called "Find and add next"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in R-Markdown files. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @lusk Unfortunately, the built-in command is only scoped for the editor window and not the Markdown window. This can be seen under scope when looking at the keyboard shortcuts (Preferences -> Code -> Modify_Keyboard_Shortcuts).
I think you could add the functionality to the Markdown window via [rstudio addins](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) but this is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac, I use `command+f` to call Find with a selected string and then use `control+g` to move onto the next match.

Comment: The enter/return button will also move the cursor to the next match

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be over 30 characters, but only needs 2:

<kbd>F3</kbd>

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek - Can you expand on this answer? I don't understand what you're getting at. Thanks

Comment: @stackinator I am not the author of the answer, I just edited it with some formatting. If you have questions on it you need to ask its author: A.Fowler

Comment: Sorry, I was just saying that the minimum number of characters on the answer was 30, but only needed 2 -- to type F3! Sorry if unclear....